# Rails sets cookies in response but headers get lost

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get Rails 4 to set some cookies on jQuery ajax post (request from a different origin)

When inside the controller, the cookies are successfully added to the `response.headers` as well as the `response.cookies` attributes:

```rb
def index
    response.set_cookie :foo, 'bar'
    response.set_cookie :baz, value: true, path: '/'
    render json: { success: true }, status: 200
  end
```

response.headers: `{"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff", "Set-Cookie"=>"foo=bar\nbaz=true; path=/"}`

response.cookies: `{"foo"=>"bar", "baz"=>"true"}`

yet the jquery promise does not seem to receive this data, rather the following:

```
.done( function(response, status, jqXHR){
        console.log('header!', jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders())
      })
```

output: header! content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to set `credentials: true` in Rack:Ccors configuration